# cannot delete virtual cluster from azure portal ,it takes long time but still exists

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I deleted an SQL managed instance before and also want to deleted related resource ,but they cannot be deleted due to virtual cluster ,I try to delete it, but it takes long time for deleting as below screenshot ,but the virtual cluster still exists

[image]

Screenshot 2
running in Powershell for long time
[image]

Comment: It may be that the strongly related resources are not deleted, so the deletion task cannot be successfully executed.

Answer (score 2):

> You can try deleting the virtual cluster either using Azure CLI or the from the remote PowerShell.

Command to remove the virtual cluster from [Remote PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/remove-azsqlvirtualcluster?view=azps-6.0.0) :

```
Remove-AzSqlVirtualCluster
  [-Name] <String>
  [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
  [-AsJob]
  [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
  [-WhatIf]
  [-Confirm]
  [<CommonParameters>]
```

CLI cmdlet to remove the virtual cluster from [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/virtual-cluster?view=azure-cli-latest#az_sql_virtual_cluster_delete) :

```
az sql virtual-cluster delete [--ids]
                          [--name]
                          [--no-wait]
                          [--resource-group]
                          [--subscription]
```

Comment: @Alex Wang - If the above provided answer was helpful ? If so could you please accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future

Comment: I tried, but it still in running status using CLI in powershell like screenshot2

Comment: @AlexWang - could you please help us with output of the command that you have ran in the PowerShell as mentioned in screenshot2.